# How to set value on change radio button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have many radio buttons generated by **php** code:

```
<?php foreach($variant_details as $prodcut_variant): ?>
 <input type="radio" name="default_variant[]">
<?php endforeach;?>
```

it generated radion buttons like

```
   `<input type="radio" name="default_variant[]">`
   `<input type="radio" name="default_variant[]">`
   `<input type="radio" name="default_variant[]">`
```

and so on
when i click on 1st radio button, its value must be value="1"
and value of rest of the radio button must be value="0".

and if i uncheck and check another button then its value must be 1 and other's must be 0

Comment: Concatenate the value with the HTML output. What language are you trying to do this in? I don't see why it's tagged JS and PHP, surely it's one or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" class="test" name="default_variant[]">
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".test").click(function(){
   $(".test").val('0');
   $(this).val('1');
 });
});
```